# I am never correct, except for in the present, in the now, in the current

Tags: riddle

> I am never correct, except for in the present,
>   
>   in the now, in the current.
>   
>   I am hated by students, loved by teachers,
>   
>   purposely created, and accidentally created.
>   
>   I deserve a cross most of the time, but in special occasions the letter before 'w.'
>   
>   I am the arch-enemy of the double zeros.

**What am I ?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please take the Tour! I hope you stay!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### I believe the answer is

> An incorrect answer.

I am never correct, except for in the present, in the now, in the current.

> An incorrect answer is never correct except right now? But then that means that my answer is right...omg I love this riddle.

I am hated by students, loved by teachers, purposely created, and accidentally created.

> Students don't like getting the wrong answer. I suppose teachers like it when students get the wrong answer? A nice teacher might like it because it gives a good lesson to the student. An evil teacher might like it because it drags down your grade...

I deserve a cross most of the time, but in special occasions the letter before 'w.'

> When you get an answer wrong you get a cross? But sometimes you get a 'v'? Like a check mark?

I am the arch-enemy of the double zeros. What am I?

> The double-zeros could mean 100 or full-marks. And an incorrect answer would definitely be the arch-enemy of a 100% on a test.

Comment: until the "double zeros" part, I was sure the answer would be time. - which is only correct in the present, hated by students since they might be late or have deadlines, and teacher love punctuality - Nobody created time, but we purposely created the notion of time - The V part could be a reference to the victor time zone, which uses military time, but is 9 hours off. - this answer makes more sense though!

Comment: Reasonable answer. As for the 3rd part, I think [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/17101/check-and-circle-marks-in-test-papers) may do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Current/Present time

**Explanation follows**

I am never correct, except for in the present, 
in the now, in the current.

> current time will be correct only when it's answered and that answer becomes wrong from the next moment.

I am hated by students, loved by teachers, 
purposely created, and accidentally created.

> In elementary school, most of the time question asked by teachers in class and tests are find the time with the diagram of a clock.

I deserve a cross most of the time, but in special occasions the letter before 'w.'

> Letter before w is V. And at 11:05 or 12:55, the clock hand resembles 'V'

I am the arch-enemy of the double zeros.

> 00 is considered as 12 in the case of time.

Comment: I like this, +1, but not sure it fits perfectly as you go from "time" to "a clock face". Depends on the author's intent.